# How does Arrays.Sort work exactly?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, quicksort, median

I was looking at the source code here: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Arrays.java#Arrays.sort%28int%5B%5D%2Cint%2Cint%29

So, basically it uses a quicksort, but the base case is when the array is small enough to use an insertion sort (size < 7). If the size is equal to 7 it chooses the pivot as the middle element. If size is > 7 is when I get confused. I see that it gets the median if size is less than 40, but how does that med3 method work exactly? If size if bigger than 40 it becomes even more complicated.

How does the method find the median and what exactly does it do if size > 40?

Comment: Were you aware that this code is from 2007?  Looks to me like it's from Java 6.  I think they've been tweaking the sorting algorithms since then, but I'm not sure.  I'm pretty sure they've changed the sort that works on `Object[]`; I'm not sure about `int[]`.

Comment: If you want to learn about sort algorithm, there are much better ways to do that than reading the Java Runtime Library source code, especially since different versions of Java uses different algorithms.

Comment: @Andreas Actually, the source code he pointed to contains a reference that looks like it might be worth reading.  (Haven't read it myself, though.)  The Java 7 and 8 versions probably contain other references worth reading (especially about Timsort).

Answer (score 1):

If the size is greater than 7 but less than 40 it will use the median of the start, end and mid point as the pivot value.

If size > 40 it takes the pivot value to be the median of 9 values aproximately equally spaced within the array.